# Getting Error while using feed-forward backpropagation network in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

While running the given code, I am getting Error

> Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Feed forward Back propagation network is used for training and testing.I am using 14 images for training, 23 for testing. The desired output is divided into 7 image classes.

```
clc
l_code=1000;
P1=zeros(l_code,14);
T = [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
     0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
     0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
     0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
     0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
     0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
     0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1];

fid1= fopen('C:\Source Code\files\output1.txt','w+');

%---------------------------Executing Files---------------------------
for i=1:14
    [c1]= HGR(['C:\Source Code\images\training\hand' int2str((i)) '.jpg']);
    %c=imresize(c,[10 10]);
    %c1=reshape(c,100,1);
    %c1 = transpose(c1);
    P1(:,i)=c1(:);

    fprintf(fid1,'Hand (%d)\r\n',i);
end;
fclose(fid1);

%------------------------Neural Network-------------------------
net = newff(minmax(P1),[l_code 7],{'tansig', 'purelin'});  
net.trainParam.epochs = 500;
net.trainParam.show=NaN;
net.trainParam.goal=0;
%net.trainParam.min_grad=1e-6;
net = train(net,P1,T,'useGPU','yes');

nn_train = fopen('C:\Source Code\files\NN Training.txt','w+');

for g=1:23
[f1]= HGR(['C:\Source Code\images\final\hand (' int2str((g)) ').jpg']);
A = transpose(f1);
A = double(A);
Y = sim(net,A);

maximum = max(Y);

for p = 1:7
    if(Y(p) == maximum)
    if (p == 1)
        fprintf(fid1,'hand(%d) : Class A\r\n',g);
    elseif (p == 2)
            fprintf(fid1,'hand(%d) : Class B\r\n',g);
    elseif (p == 3)
            fprintf(fid1,'hand(%d) : Class C\r\n',g);
    elseif (p == 4)
            fprintf(fid1,'hand(%d) : Class D\r\n',g);
    elseif (p == 5)
            fprintf(fid1,'hand(%d) : Class E\r\n',g);
    elseif (p == 6)
            fprintf(fid1,'hand(%d) : Class F',g);
    elseif (p == 7)
            fprintf(fid1,'hand(%d) : Class G\r\n',g);
    end;
    end;
end;
end;
```

Screenshot of the **Error**:

[image]

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You ran out of memory. What does `memory` print?

Comment: That error is resolved by changing value of `net.trainParam.epochs = 100;` However, now I am getting similar error for `Y = sim(net,A);`